# Object of type X can not be assigned because of its copy operator implicitly delated

Tags: c++, c++14

I want to have a structure `B` that contains an `unordered_map` which as a value has another `struct A` which has a member a base object of type `BASE`. I do this because I want to be able to store objects of `TYPE1` AND `TYPE2`. To have a base class as a member I had to make declare it as a reference (see code below):

My problem is, that I can not add anything to the `unordered_map` `meta` because it says:

```
object of type 'A' cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted
    meta.H["str"] = tmp_hdr;

note: copy assignment operator of 'A' is implicitly deleted because field 'hdr' is of reference type 'BASE &'
    BASE & hdr;
```

Simplified code:

```cpp
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

class BASE {
public:
    BASE();
    virtual void doSomething()=0;  
    virtual ~BASE() {};
};

class TYPE1 : public BASE {
public:
    TYPE1();
    virtual void doSomething() {};
};

class TYPE2 : public BASE {
public:
    TYPE2();
    virtual void doSomething() {};
};

  struct A{
    bool valid;
    BASE & hdr;
  };

  struct B{
    uint16_t out=-1;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, A&> H;
  };    



int main(void)
{
    TYPE1 b;
    A tmp_hdr = {true, b}; 
    B meta;
    meta.H["str"] = tmp_hdr;

    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better or different way to achieve what I want?

Comment: But does not have something todo with the fact that my BASE object can not be copied?

Comment: Using a reference for this looks quite evil to me, what about the scope of the referenced object? Typically a pointer, or smart pointer, is used in these cases.

Comment: These references seem excessive. Why not just let it copy? I suspect either you are doing premature optimization, or you need smart pointers.

Comment: @KennyOstrom He is using references because he wants to store specialized objects in a base class container. However, this is what pointers are for :)

Comment: @ypnos: pointer has same issue than reference about scoping. reference enforce non null pointer. its drawback is that it is not copyable (neither default constructible), making its usage harder.

Comment: @Jarod42 I disagree because in the example above, `A tmp_hdr = {true, &b};` would make obvious what is going on. But my comment is just a general note, I am sure there are cases where deliberately using references is not a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

There are restrictions on allowed types for key and value depending on method used. Reference isn't default constructible, which is required for `operator []` which might create default value.

You might use `emplace` instead:

```
meta.H.emplace("str", tmp_hdr);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3248d7661a1f8397)

Comment: Is there any reason why clang wont compile that? I managed with g++ and c++14. 

What is the difference between `[]` and `emplace` ? I got a quite lost.

Comment: `operator[]` does mostly `emplace(key, {}).first.second` (the first.second is to return associated value), so default construct value, and `A&` is not default constructible.

Comment: Demo link use both clang and gcc.

Comment: Fixed, sorry! Is there in general a more elegant way of doing what I am trying to do? I am not a c++ expert and come from python so I managed to do this after a lot of trial and error but at some point I got a bit lost: for example why the BASE class needs to be a reference.